# Google maps API, callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asynchronous, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to use callback function in my code to show markers on map, every foreach address. Before I have to geocode address.

```
function initMap() {
    GetLatLon('@(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model‌​.Maps)))', function(location) {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 2,
            center: location
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
           addMarker('@(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model‌​.Maps)))', map, i);
        }
    });
  }

function addMarker (location, map, count) {
    var locationArr = JSON.parse(location);
    console.log (count);
    GetLatLonByAddress(locationArr[count]), function(addr){
        //alert(addr);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: addr,
            map: map
        });
    }
}

function GetLatLonByAddress (address, callbackAddr) {
    console.log(address);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            location = { lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(), lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng() };
            callbackAddr(location);
        } 
    });
}
```

But `callbackAddr(location);` returns an error by JS Console: `Uncaught TypeError: callbackAddr is not a function(…)`
How can I fix?

Comment: You have a closing bracket after passing the first location when calling the `GetLatLonByAddress`

Comment: @Shyju I don't understand what row you mean to. Can you write the row?

Comment: Found :) I resolved